# Using Terraform we have to create user and password for windows VM that we have created through terraform

Tags: google-compute-engine

The issue that we are facing that we have created the Windows VM through terraform and we have to connect through terraform so we are not able to add username and password for newly created windows VM through terraform

Comment: Show your Terraform code and what you tried with error messages, etc.

Answer (score 2):

As of writing, Terraform's officially documented way to generate GCP Windows VM password doesn't really work due to missing TLS utility (we should generate a one-time cert every time and calculate its modulus):
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/compute_instance_serial_port

My hack is to run a `local-exec` provisioner to run the `gcloud` command to generate password

```
gcloud compute reset-windows-password <...> --quiet | tee > $(grep password | cut -d ' ' -f2- | tr -d '\n' > pass.txt)
```

... then write it to a file, and read it where it's needed, e.g. as an output.

It's working pretty well for me. But remember to `time_sleep` for about 4 minutes after a VM gets freshly created, otherwise the command will fail without error.

Also, this will add a few more overhead to your pipeline. You need to setup and `gcloud auth login`, which supposedly isn't necessary with just using native gcp provider. And since it writes password to a intermediate file, if you are running your Terraform pipeline in a ephemeral environment (e.g. docker), it's going to be a bit tricky to manage its state.

Comment: Hi @mnt, `--quite` flag is mispelled, it should be `--quiet`. Also, I had to add a dollar sign `$` before the parenthesis before the `grep`, otherwise a syntax error is thrown

Comment: Thanks @DevilingMaster! Fixed the typos.